# Determine the quotient space $P$/$U_{e}$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**

Let $P$ be the vector space of all real polynomials. Let $U_{e}$ be the set of even polynomials; that is, those that satisfy $p(t) = p(-t)$. Show that $U_{e}$ is a subspace of $P$, and determine the quotient space $P$/$U_{e}$. (In this context, "determine" means to find a subspace of $P$ that is isomorphic to $P$/$U_{e}$ in a natural way.)

**Attempted solution**

Showing that $U_{e}$ is a subspace of $P$ is not a problem. The other part however...

We have that

$U_{e}$ = {$p$ $\in$ $P$ : $p(t)$ = $p(-t)$}

Let $x$, $y$ $\in$ $P$ and we say that $x$~$y$ if $x$-$y$ $\in$ $U_{e}$. With this equivalence relation we can go further and say
$x$-$y$ = $y_{e}$ where $y_{e}$ $\in$ $U_{e}$

From this equivalence relation we can establish an equivalence class:

$\bar{x}$ = $y$ + $U_{e}$ = {$y$ + $y_{e}$ : $y_{e}$ $\in$ $U_{e}$}

The quotient space is simply the set of equivalence classes:

$P$/$U_{e}$ = {$\bar{x}$ : $y$ $\in$ $P$}

However, since a polynomial can always be written as a combination of an even and odd part we have that $y$ = $y_{e}$ + $y_{o}$, where $y_{o}$ is an odd polynomial. This means $\bar{x}$ = $y_{e}$ + $y_{o}$ + $U_{e}$ = $y_{o}$ + $U_{e}$. However, I don't really know what I have achieved at this point. 
I am guessing that what I have found at this point does not qualify as the quotient space as the question hints towards finding an isomorphism between a subspace of $P$ and $P$/$U_{e}$. The subspace of $P$ must be the set of odd polynomials, call it $U_{o}$, and I must show that there exist a bijective linear transformation $\phi$ such that:

$\phi$ : $U_{o}$ -> $P$/$U_{e}$

But how does this determine the quotient space, compared to the set of equivalence classes?  If there exist an isomorphism between $U_{o}$ and $P$/$U_{e}$ does this imply that the quotient space is the set of odd polynomials? And how would I show that this isomorphism exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define $L:P \to P$ by $L(p)(t) = {1 \over 2} (p(t) - p(-t))$. Then $p \in U_e$ **iff** $p \in \ker L$, and hence $U_e = \ker L$ and so is a subspace.

It is not hard to establish that $Lp$ is an odd polynomial, and furthermore, if $p$ is odd, $p = Lp$. Hence ${\cal R} L = U_o$.

The first isomorphism theorem tells us that $P / \ker L \simeq {\cal R} L$.

**Note**: ${\cal R L} = \{ Lp | p \in P \}$.

Comment: You say that if $p$ is odd then $L(p)$ = $p$ and hence $R$$L$ = $U_{o}$. But what is $R$?

Comment: The range of $L$.

Comment: In general when you show that there exists an isomorphism between two vector spaces, does that mean they are equal? In this case does it mean that the quotient space $P$/$U_{e}$ = $U_{o}$?

Comment: No, they are not necessary equal. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{R}$  (that is, take $x \sim y$ **iff** $x_2=y_2$) are isomorphic, but points in the first are numbers, points in the second are lines. In the example above, $P /U_e$ are equivalence classes of polynomials, $U_0$ consists of polynomials.

Comment: Delighted to be of help.